# Run MARIONETTE instead gecko

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to run selenium with marionette, but after run nothing showing

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        FirefoxOptions options= new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, false);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("www.google.com");

    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginAndHomePage() {
        login = new LoginPage(driver);
        String loginPageTitle = login.getLoginTitle();
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPageTitle.contains("GOOGLE"));
        System.out.println("Test Passed");
    }
```

Is it possible to run marionette without `System.setProperty()` ?

Comment: Yes take older version of FF below 44

Comment: @Ankur Singh but can i use 60 FF and higher?

Comment: Take Firefox 52 ESR, that's the last one which supports Legacy.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: @Rajagopalan but If I want to use FF >60 I can use DriverManager

Comment: @HardExploder If you want to use Firefox>60 then you need to use geckodriver.

Comment: @Rajagopalan thanks